# How to get the count of isomorphisms between two graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have two weighted isomorphic graphs. How can I figure out how many isomorphisms between them there are?Please don't use "brute force" to do that.If it's too difficult,we can reduce the difficulty of the problem by change the question to how to figure out if there is only one isomorphism between these two graphs or not.Answer can be choosed from three options:have no isomorphism,only have one,have more than one.Thank you very much.

Comment: You should probably qualify your question. As it stands, 'brute force' seems a reasonable answer.

Comment: Yes,you are right,spaceisdarkgreen.I will edit the question again.

Comment: If you are looking for a software package, it sounds like the [igraph library](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Isomorphism.html#igraph_count_isomorphisms_vf2)  The edge colors (or vertex colors) can be used in place of weights.

Comment: Yes,saulspatz,I'm looking for a software package or an algorithm.I have used [igraph library](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Isomorphism.html#igraph_count_isomorphisms_vf2) but I didn't find any method can solve this directly.Just like what you said,the edge colors in my graph represent the weight of graph.

Comment: Why doesn't `igraph_count_isomorphisms_vf2` solve your problem?  From the description, it sounds like just the ticket.  Is your graph too big for it to handle? 
 Just asking, I have no experience with igraph.

Comment: Even distinguishing between "no isomorphism" and "one or more isomorphisms" is a problem of unknown complexity, suspected to be NP-intermediate. If you can find an algorithm that is significantly faster than brute force, you'll be famous!

Comment: OK,saulspatz,I will have a try.I left it out.Thank you.And if it really solved my question,what should I do with the question I asked here?

Comment: Hahaha,you got the point,Henning.I am trying to find out the famous man.

Comment: Good news,@saulspatz! **igraph_count_isomorphisms_vf2** really helps me,thank you again.